# Accessing the version on an SPFolder

Tags: object-model, versioning

Within a Document Library with versioning turned on, I noticed that if I create a folder and "View Properties" that there is a "Version: 1.0" that is listed as a property along with "Created By", etc. at the bottom of the page. How do I retrieve this Version value using the SPFolder object?

Answer (score 1):

SPFolder has the property [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.item.aspx) which gives you the folder's associated list item. This object should have the version and other field values.

Comment: Yes, but the SPListItem only has a Versions (with an 's') property, not an Version (without an 's') property. How do I determine which of the Versions corresponds to the SPFolder that I have?

Comment: Now this makes me wonder if folders actually have a version that can change, or if it's just there because a folder is a list item. It looks like they probably don't - changing the name doesn't change the version number, and the version history button is greyed out in the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

If you were not aware, the Folder object is still considered to be an item in the list. It is just an item of the folder type. So in a lot of cases it is treated like a regular list item. So it just depends on what method you are using to get at this. Client side code or server side code.

Comment: Nuts, I forgot to mention in my question that this was SP2007 object model -- so it is server side code.